# Loading form submit inside content tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I am looking to have the results from the form listed below in one template (register.html) to be loaded into a content tag within a separate html file (index.html). The goal is to have the form submit load in the center of index.html. However right now, it is loading a separate page, thus redirecting the user away from index.html. Anyone savvy with javascript that could help with a solution? Thank you so much!

where content is to be loaded within index.html:

```
<content class="loadContent">
</content>
```

register.html form:

```
<div class="registration_form">
    {% block content %}
     <form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="/register_temp/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

        <ul style="position:relative; top:20px;">
        <li id="username_registration"><p>Username:</p>{{ form.username }}</li> 
        <li id="email_registration" class=""><p>Email:</p>{{ form.email}}</li>
        <li id="password1_registration" class=""><p>Password:</p>{{ form.password1 }}</li>
        <li id="password2_registration" class=""><p>Password confirmation:</p
        {{ form.password2 }}</li>
        </ul>

        <input name="registerform" id="registerform" class="registration_button" type="submit" value="Register" style="position:relative; left:55px;" onclick="userform();" />

        </form>
     {% endblock %}
 </div>
```

the javascript in register.html:

```
<script>

    function userform() {
    document.getElementById('registerform').submit();
    }


</script>
```

I have been able to get other links to load inside the center of the index with this code (but have yet to find a solution for the form submission results to do so also): (note: the "splash" that is being referenced in the script is the div id containing everything in the body of register.html.

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $('').on('click', function( e ){   
    });

    var wrap = $('content');

    $('#splash a').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen :

- there is a typo (you have a p tag that is not cleanly closed, after the password2 field). It might create problem with the rest of the form.
- you have 2 tags with the same id, "registerform". So your document.getElementById('registerform') may not work properly.

Apart from that, I don't get how this should work. You're submiting the form to another page (/register_temp/) so it seems logical that the current page changes.

Maybe I didn't get what you wanted to do, but as I understood, you don't want to submit the form the html way, but you rather want to do it using Ajax.

Brice

Comment: I'm not sure why the p tag came through like that. It's correct in my code. I guess it just got messed up when I pasted it and formatted things. I just changed each tag so it is unique and referenced the form id and not the input id. It still works accordingly. I want /register_temp/ to load inside of my index.html template. I don't want the page to change. I was able to do this with all other href tags by using the javascript posted at the bottom of the page. I can not do this with form submission results which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: it would seem ajax might be the way to do this. However, I am unfamiliar with doing this way. Suggestions?

Comment: You should take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . Playing with the examples 'Send form data using ajax requests' to send your form data and 'Post a form using ajax and put results in a div' to put the result of an ajax query in a div, you should do be able to do what you want.

Comment: I will definitely read that. I'm not sure if that is going to do the trick though. The form is being derived from a django view and upon validation of registration, the user is directed to a separate html file/url upon success. That html file/url is not being loaded inside of the index.html, like the registration.html file. It is loaded outside of it. The issue is that the registration form data is being validated but then after that, the user is being directed to the /register_success/ url that isn't being loaded in the middle of index. If that makes sense, would ajax still be appropriate?

Comment: I didn't get everything but : if you want to submit your form and have a redirect whatever the response was, just use plain html submit button. If in some cases you want to stay on the same page and update its contents, use ajax. You'll be able to change the page using js if you need to. Also, if your form is using the csrf protection, you'll probably have to use something like this : https://gist.github.com/alanhamlett/6316427